# CSS background image does not show when relative path used

Tags: css, javafx

I'm working on project in JavaFX. File structure looks like this (CEP is the root):

```
CEP
  +img
     menu.jpg
  +src
     +css_files
        MainMenu.css
```

What I want to do is to set background image from img directory in MainMenu.css file. So far I have tried different urls (see below), but none of them worked.

```
-fx-background-image: url("./CEP/img/menu.jpg");
-fx-background-image: url("../CEP/img/menu.jpg");
-fx-background-image: url("CEP/img/menu.jpg");
-fx-background-image: url("/CEP/img/menu.jpg");
-fx-background-image: url("../../img/menu.jpg");
-fx-background-image: url("/img/menu.jpg");
-fx-background-image: url("./img/menu.jpg");
-fx-background-image: url("../img/menu.jpg");
-fx-background-image: url("img/menu.jpg");
```

If I use full path like this

```
-fx-background-image: url("file:///C:/Users/Konrad/Desktop/java/CEP/img/menu.jpg");
```

everything works fine but that is not what I want to do. How can I load my background image using relative path?

Edit.
As requested, here is `build` folder structure:

```
build
   +classes
      +css_files
      +(other folders)
      menu.jpg
   +empty (empty)
   +generated-sources (has 1 empty subfolder)
```

Comment: It looks like `img` is *outside* of the `src` folder hierarchy. Is that correct? So have you configured `img` as a "source folder" (in Eclipse terminology: not sure how that translates to other IDEs). If so, you probably just need `url("/menu.jpg")`.  What might be more useful is if you show the structure of your output folder (i.e. the structure under the classpath). You should have a `bin` or `build` folder somewhere in your project.

Comment: `img` is outside of the `src` folder, you are right. I'm using NetBeans, when I created new folder for images it didn't show up in "project tree", but it shows in "files tree" so I thought it's ok (I know new folder would be visible in Eclipse, I don't know why here it is not).

Comment: So does the image file appear anywhere in the folder that contains the class files (probably called `bin`, `build`, `target`, or `classes`)?

Comment: I have changed build path so now images are in `build` folder, but still it doesn't work

Comment: See answer (including update for your latest edit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `img` folder, and its contents, are not part of your source folder hierarchy, and consequently are not being deployed as part of the application. You can either configure your IDE to deploy the contents of that folder, or more simply move `img` (and its content) into `src`.

If you do the latter, then `img` will be at the root of the classpath after deployment, alongside `css_files`, so either of

```css
-fx-background-image: url("/img/menu.jpg");
```

or

```css
-fx-background-image: url("../img/menu.jpg");
```

should work.

On the other hand, if you configure `img` as a source folder, then the contents of `img` will be placed at the root of the classpath. In this case, that means `menu.jpg` will be at the root of the classpath, so you would need one of

```css
-fx-background-image: url("/menu.jpg");
```

or

```css
-fx-background-image: url("../menu.jpg");
```

Comment: I used your last suggestion (-fx-background-image: url("/menu.jpg"), it all works now. Thank you very much